# My car battery light is on

Tags: battery, toyota, alternator, corolla, charging

I have a 2010 Toyota Corolla S. Today, after driving around for 15 minutes, when I parked, my battery light came on. I took it to Autozone. After checking my battery and the changing system they said, everything seems ok. Nothing pop up in their machine. I was wondering what could cause this problem. I replace my battery in December 2019. And I replace my alternator 2 weeks ago.

> N.B:
>
> The first time I saw that the battery light came on, I turn off my
> engine for 5 minutes and then start again, the battery sign was off.
> After running the engine for 3/4 minutes, it came back on.
>
> While I start the car for driving to AutoZone, the battery light was
> off. Again after 4/5 minutes, It came on while I was driving. My
> battery sign was still on, while the guy from AutoZone was checking
> both the battery & the changing system. Then I turn off and on my
> engine, that sign went off again.

Any comments, what might cause the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify if the battery light was on while the engine was running? Or did it come on after the engine stopped?

Comment: Well, as you mention it does this while driving @GdD, then it may be a loose connection or a broken wire or it could be shorting something to go into an overcharging mode which may also put the light on - that depends on the system. This means you have to start checking wires, connections etc very carefully.

Comment: All true @SolarMike, I was thinking that if it only comes on with the engine stopped it's completely normal .

Comment: @SolarMike, any idea, how much it will cost to fix in case of a broken wire or to fix shorting?

Comment: @user45698746 cost questions are not acceptable on here. Depends on how long it takes to find, not how long it takes to repair / replace the wire / terminal....